# struts2 result in iframe

Tags: java, html, web, struts2

I'm using struts2 in a netbeans webapp project. The idea is as follows:

I made a web app where you put a text in a textarea, then, you click a button and each word is  compared in a DataBase. The words that matches appears in an iframe just below of the textarea.

This proccess is done by now with Servlets and works fine, but... How can i do this in struts2?

I have the next code:

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="NLPServStruts" class="com.uem.gsi.tmt.action.NLPServStrutsAction">
            <result>/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-15"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Tourist Face Web Tool: Tourist Text</title>
<!--<link type="text/css" href="themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themes/base/ui.all.css">
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST id="submit" action="/TouristFaceStruts/NLPServStruts" target=output>
<h1>Tourist Face Tool (TMT)</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <button type=submit id="bSearch" style="font-size: 1.2em;"
                class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
            PROCESS TEXT</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <SELECT NAME="selCombo" SIZE=1 onchange="descargaVideo(value);cargaTexto(value);"> 
            <%= line %>
            </SELECT>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <textarea name="text" id="txTourism" rows="10"
            cols="72"></textarea>
            <p>
        <iframe name="output" id="output"
            height="200" width="600">
        </iframe>   
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="myDiv" name="myDiv"> 
                <OBJECT name="movie5" id="movie5" CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" WIDTH="560" HEIGHT="350" >
                    <PARAM NAME="autoplay" VALUE="true" >
                </OBJECT>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
<!--<input type=submit value=Submit>--></form>
<!--<div name="output" id="output"></div>-->

<div id="loading"
    class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<p>Loading...</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet.java

```
package com.uem.gsi.tmt.serv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.uem.gsi.tmt.nlp.GateGazTour;
/*RAFA
 * import com.uem.gsi.tmt.nlp.NCBOAnnot;
 RAFA*/

/**
 * Servlet implementation class NLPServ
 */
public class NLPServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public NLPServ() {
        super();
        System.out.println("constructor");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* RAFA
         * String lev=(request.getParameter("lev")!=null)?request.getParameter("lev"):"0";
        String onts=(request.getParameter("onts")!=null)?request.getParameter("onts"):"40397"; //Medlineplus
        RAFA */

        String text=(request.getParameter("text")!=null)?request.getParameter("text"):"";
        String nlpResults="";
        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if (text.equals("")){
            //out.println("Text to annotate can't be null");        
            nlpResults="Text to annotate can't be null";
        }else{
            try {
                //GATE Annotation
                //out.println(htmlGateTree(text));
                nlpResults=htmlGateTree(text);

                //NCBO Annotation
                /*NCBOAnnotCall oNCBO=new NCBOAnnotCall();
                oNCBO.setText(text);
                oNCBO.setOntInRes(onts);
                oNCBO.setlevelMax(lev);
                //out.println(oNCBO.doRESTQuery());
                //out.println(htmlNCBOTree(text,oNCBO.doRESTQuery()));
                nlpResults+=htmlNCBOTree(text,oNCBO.doRESTQuery());*/
                /*RAFA
                 * NCBOAnnot ncboAnnot=new NCBOAnnot();
                 RAFA*/
                //System.out.println("level: "+lev);
                /*RAFA
                ncboAnnot.runNCBOAnnot(text, onts, lev);
                nlpResults+=htmlNCBOTree(ncboAnnot);
                RAFA*/
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            //out.println(e.toString());
            nlpResults=e.toString();
        }
        }
        request.setAttribute("nlpResults", nlpResults);
        getServletConfig().getServletContext().
            getRequestDispatcher("/nlpresult.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }
    private String htmlGateTree(String text) throws Exception {

        String result="";

        String sc = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");


        GateGazTour gateAnnot=new GateGazTour(sc);
        gateAnnot.runGazetteer(text);
        //Add value just if is not repeated
        List<String> lTouristT=gateAnnot.getTouristAttraction(),lTouristAttraction=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lAccommodationT=gateAnnot.getAccommodation(),lAccommodation=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lTravelDestinationT=gateAnnot.getTravelDestination(),lTravelDestination=new ArrayList<String>();
        //List<String> lFromT=gateAnnot.getFrom(),lFrom=new ArrayList<String>();
        //List<String> lToT=gateAnnot.getTo(),lTo=new ArrayList<String>();
        int sizeT=lTouristT.size();
        for (int i=0;i<sizeT;i++){
            if (!lTouristAttraction.contains(lTouristT.get(i))){
                lTouristAttraction.add(lTouristT.get(i));
                //lFrom.add(lFromT.get(i));
                //lTo.add(lToT.get(i));
            }
        }
        sizeT=lAccommodationT.size();
        for (int i=0;i<sizeT;i++)
            if (!lAccommodation.contains(lAccommodationT.get(i)))
                lAccommodation.add(lAccommodationT.get(i));

        sizeT=lTravelDestinationT.size();
        for (int i=0;i<sizeT;i++)
            if (!lTravelDestination.contains(lTravelDestinationT.get(i)))
                lTravelDestination.add(lTravelDestinationT.get(i));

        //

        Iterator<String> iter = lTouristAttraction.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            String annotName=iter.next();
            result+="<tr>";
            result+="<td><a href='fbresulttou.jsp?term="+annotName+"' target=_blank>"+annotName+"</a></td>";
            result+="<td>Freebase Tourist Attraction</td>";
            //result+="<td></td>";
            //result+="<td>Freebase Disease</td>";
            //result+="<td>Gazetteer</td>";
            result+="</tr>";
        }
        iter = lAccommodation.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            String annotName=iter.next();
            result+="<tr>";
            result+="<td><a href='fbresultaco.jsp?term="+annotName+"' target=_blank>"+annotName+"</a></td>";
            result+="<td>Freebase Accommodation</td>";
            //result+="<td></td>";
            //result+="<td>Freebase Symptom</td>";
            //result+="<td>Gazetteer</td>";
            result+="</tr>";
        }
        iter = lTravelDestination.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            String annotName=iter.next();
            result+="<tr>";
            result+="<td><a href='fbresulttra.jsp?term="+annotName+"' target=_blank>"+annotName+"</a></td>";
            result+="<td>Freebase Travel Destination</td>";
            //result+="<td></td>";
            //result+="<td>Freebase Treatment</td>";
            //result+="<td>Gazetteer</td>";
            result+="</tr>";
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*RAFA
    private String htmlNCBOTree(NCBOAnnot oNCBOAnnot) throws Exception {
        String result="";
        //Add value just if is not repeated
        List<String> lConceptT=oNCBOAnnot.getConcept(),lConcept=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lLocalOntologyIdT=oNCBOAnnot.getLocalOntologyId(),lLocalOntologyId=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lFullIdT=oNCBOAnnot.getFullId(),lFullId=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lIsDirectT=oNCBOAnnot.getIsDirect(),lIsDirect=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lFromT=oNCBOAnnot.getFrom(),lFrom=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lToT=oNCBOAnnot.getTo(),lTo=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lPreferredNameT=oNCBOAnnot.getPreferredName(),lPreferredName=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lContextNameT=oNCBOAnnot.getContextName(),lContextName=new ArrayList<String>();
        int sizeT=lConceptT.size();
        for (int i=0;i<sizeT;i++){
            if (!lConcept.contains(lConceptT.get(i))){
                lConcept.add(lConceptT.get(i));
                lLocalOntologyId.add(lLocalOntologyIdT.get(i));
                lFullId.add(lFullIdT.get(i));
                lIsDirect.add(lIsDirectT.get(i));
                lPreferredName.add(lPreferredNameT.get(i));
                lContextName.add(lContextNameT.get(i));
            }
        }
        //
        int size=lConcept.size();
        //Paint results     
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
            if (lLocalOntologyId.get(i).equals("40397")){
            result+="<tr><td><a href='/MedicalFace/mlpresult.jsp?term="+
                    lConcept.get(i)+"' target=_blank>"+lConcept.get(i)+
                    "</a></td><td>MedlinePlus</td></tr>";
                    //lFullId.get(i)+"</td><td>"+
                    //lPreferredName.get(i);
                    //"</td><td>"+lContextName.get(i)+"</td></tr>";
        }else{  
            result+="<tr><td>"+lConcept.get(i)+"</td><td>"+lLocalOntologyId.get(i)+
                "</td></td></tr>";
                //lFullId.get(i)+"</td><td>"+
                //lPreferredName.get(i)+"</td></tr>";
                //"</td><td>"+lContextName.get(i)+"</td></tr>";
        }
        }
        return result;
/*      Document doc = MyDOMParserBean.getDocument(xml);
        NodeList listAnnot=doc.getElementsByTagName("annotationBean");
        String result="";
        for (int i=0;i<listAnnot.getLength();i++){
            result+="<tr>";
          //Initialize data to show
          String localOntologyId="",fullId="",preferredName="";
          String contextName="",isDirect="",from="",to="",nameInText="";
          Node annotNode=listAnnot.item(i);
          //System.out.println(listAnnot.item(i).getNodeName());
          NodeList listChildAnnot=annotNode.getChildNodes();
          for (int j=0;j<listChildAnnot.getLength();j++){
            Node nodeTemp1=listChildAnnot.item(j);
            //System.out.println(nodeTemp1.getNodeName());
            //Concept
            if (nodeTemp1.getNodeName().equals("concept")){
              //System.out.println(nodeTemp1.getNodeName());
              NodeList listChildRes=nodeTemp1.getChildNodes();
              for (int k=0;k<listChildRes.getLength();k++){
                Node node1=listChildRes.item(k);
                String node1name=node1.getNodeName();
                //Elements selection
                if (node1name.equals("localOntologyId"))
                  localOntologyId=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                else if (node1name.equals("fullId"))
                  fullId=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                else if (node1name.equals("preferredName"))
                  preferredName=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
              }

            }//Context
            else if (nodeTemp1.getNodeName().equals("context")){
              //System.out.println(nodeTemp1.getNodeName());
              NodeList listChildRes=nodeTemp1.getChildNodes();
              for (int k=0;k<listChildRes.getLength();k++){
                Node node1=listChildRes.item(k);
                String node1name=node1.getNodeName();
                //System.out.println(node1.getNodeName()+"="+node1.getNodeValue());
                //Seleccionar elementos
                if (node1name.equals("contextName"))
                  contextName=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                else if (node1name.equals("isDirect"))
                  isDirect=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                else if (node1name.equals("from"))
                  from=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();
                else if (node1name.equals("to"))
                  to=node1.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().trim();

               }//else if (node1name.equals("term"))
             }
          }
        nameInText=text.substring(new Integer(from)-1,new Integer(to));
        //System.out.println(localOntologyId+","+fullId+","+preferredName+","+
        //    contextName+","+isDirect+","+from+","+to+","+nameInText);
        //if (localOntologyId.equals("40397"))
        nameInText="<a href='"+fullId+"'>"+nameInText+"</a>";
        result+="<td>"+nameInText+"</td><td>"+localOntologyId+"</td><td>"+
                fullId+"</td><td>"+preferredName+"</td><td>"+contextName+"</td>";
        result+="</tr>";
        }
        return result;*/
    /*}  RAFA*/

        /*Jorge de Lemos Martín*/

        protected void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

So, the problem is: when I click on the button, in the iframe loads the same page index.jsp 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The result of your action is `index.jsp` and it shows. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: That's the point How can i do to show the result as a table with each word that has been detected? With servlets it works fine.

Comment: Try to explain what exactly is not working.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, thank you so much.

In the servlet, the response is a table wich contains the words that matches.

How can i do this with struts2?

Comment: I suggest you to do it with an AJAX request (jQuery), that call an Action, and return a JSP snippet (or a JSON object) to be injected in a target div.

Answer (score 0):

I think iframe load is missing in your code...
you have to load iframe

Just search in google you will find it

for example:

```
<iframe class='xyz' src='xyz.jsp'></iframe>

<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="NLPServStruts" class="com.uem.gsi.tmt.action.NLPServStrutsAction">
            <result>/xyz.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Comment: Thank you Narayan!!! So I have to load that page in my iframe, but one question, this iframe is dynamically generated, so how can I do that in the jsp?

In the Servlet, the response is html generated in the "Iterator<String> iter" part
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: we have to set your  result.jsp in that iframe src. I will back after 1hr

Comment: Hi Jorge,got solution for this problem

Comment: Hello Narayan, i didn't find a solutionm have you got one?

Comment: Hi jorge,My solution is do not generate html server side(using java).Just create jsp file and put reponse text or use AJAX then put jsp file in iframe src.. it sould work without any problem.

Comment: Hi Narayan, thanks for the response. The problem is that this application analize the words and put them in sets depending of the type of word: set1, set2 or set3, so, each set goes to a different page, that's why the iframe is for.

Comment: I think somehow I got it: I could send the info with the sets already made to a destiny page, as: result.jsp, then there build the table, as like the NLPServ Servlet is doing right now. The problem is: How can I send the info to the result.jsp?